# Define a 2D Gaussian probability with five peaks

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, probability

I have a 2D data and it contains five peaks. Could I fit five 2D Gaussians function to obtain the peaks?  In my problem, the peaks do not refer to the clustering problem.  Which I think EM would be an appropriate answer for it. 
In my case I measure a variable in x-y space and it shows maximum in more than one position. Is still fitting `Fourier series` or using `Expectation-Maximization` method an applicable solution to my problem?

In order to make my likelihood, do I need to just add up the five `2D Gaussians distributions` with `x` and `y` and the `height` of each peak as variables?

Comment: you can fit a Fourier series of two variables to your data using `numpy.linalg.lstsq()`, for example, and then find the peaks analytically...

Comment: @SaulloCastro can you please explain more?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, check out Gaussian Mixture Models and Expectation Maximization. I don't know of any pre-implemented versions of these in Python, although I haven't looked too hard.

Comment: A simple google would would have turned up http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html